# C++: Boost memory-mapped files (aggressive) read-ahead

Tags: performance, boost, mmap, memory-mapped-files

is it possible somehow to tell the boost mapped file to read-ahead aggressively. I am traversing a file (more or less) in order.

I saw that the traditional not portable mapped files of unix (mmap) can be created with a flag to enable just that. Can this also done with the boost equivalent?

The problem is that i am only getting half of the read performance of what would be possible through just reading the file (which is impractical, because the files are huge).

Comment: Maybe try `madvise()`?

Comment: madvice() is only for mapped regions as far as i can tell. I dont have multiple processes, just multiple threads.